# Dynamic class creation, problem with function definition inside block: function body does not see local scope

Tags: ruby, class, dynamic

I'm writing a function to dynamically create classes.  I run into a problem with the *vars variable (below), where inside the block passed to Class::new, the "def initialize" method cannot see the value of *vars  (and thus Ruby reports a unbound variable error on *vars).

What to do?

Thanks!

```
class MyParentClass
    def do_something_with(*args)
    end
    def do_something_else_with(*vars)
    end
end

def create_class(class_name,*vars)

    new_class = Class::new(MyParentClass) do
            def initialize(*args)
                super
                do_something_with(args)
                do_something_else_with(vars)
            end
        end
    Object::const_set(class_name.intern,new_class)
end 

    # Ruby: Error: *vars is unbound variable
    # My notes: *vars is in scope inside the do..end block passed to Class::new, but cannot be seen inside def initialize (why?) . And, how to fix this?
```

Comment: You can hack it using class vars to store the data, then retrieve it inside the initialize function.  However, I am looking for a cleaner solution (if any exists?)  I have tried this out and it works fine using the class_var hack.  Using class vars would make sense, because if I were to be subclassing MyParentClass myself manually, in code by typing, I would be calling "do_something_else_with(vars)" with the vars being static strings that I type into the code; I suppose typing it into the source manually is the same as storing it in a class_var dynamically - it has to be stored somewhere !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve with this contraption, but after some changes it works (well, depending on your definition of "to work"):

```
class MyParentClass
  def do_something_with(*args)
    puts "something #{args.inspect}"
  end
  def do_something_else_with(*vars)
    puts "else #{vars.inspect}"
  end
end

def create_class(class_name,*vars)

  new_class = Class::new(MyParentClass) do
    define_method :initialize do |*args|
      super()
      do_something_with(*args)
      do_something_else_with(*vars)
    end
  end
  Object::const_set(class_name.intern,new_class)
end

create_class :MyClass, 1, :foo, :bar
MyClass.new(2, :baz)
```

The trick to make `vars` visible is to define the constructor using a closure.

Comment: Wow thanks! This works great!  I didn't know there was a difference between define_method and def  ...  in this case, are you over-writing the default initialize (defined using def initialize) in some way?

Comment: What I am trying to do: parse a text file on the fly, create classes based off of what I parse. It is related to hardware engineering not software :)